# Where liveth declared but undefined global variables in Python?

Tags: python, cpython

When you state that a variable is global, it does not create it for you (if it doesn't already exist). What does the global statement **actually** do to the variable? It obviously doesn't merely modify it since it does not have to exist for it to be modified. Once this goes out of scope, can

```
def foo():
    global cat, dog
    dog = 1

foo()
print('dog' in globals())  # => True
print(dog)  # => 1
print('cat' in globals())  # => False
print(cat)  # => NameError
```

This also raises an error (not surprising):

```
def foo():
    global cat, dog
    dog = 1

def bar():
    cat = 2

foo()
bar()
print(dog)
print(cat)  # => NameError
```

So obviously the global modifier only works within the scope of the function being executed. Is this, in any way, caused by the garbage collector? Is there some phantom globalizer object that waits for the creation of an object with the given name and gets cleared up upon the end of the function?

Comment: Right but prior to assigning dog to a value, there were no instances of dog.

Comment: My point is that it's obviously not directly modifying dog because dog does not exist prior to the global statement. You cannot modify something that doesn't exist.

Comment: The garbage collector has nothing to do with it. `global` just doesn't create the variable. If you check `"cat" in globals()` inside the `foo()`, it will answer false.

Comment: You assign dog to a value in foo so I am not sure what you mean. If you were to print cat in foo you would get a NameError as it is not defined anywhere.

Comment: It seems that the interpreter register the name somewhere, so that when you create or access such names, it will refer to the global namespace.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement  *global is a directive to the parser. It applies only to code parsed at the same time as the global statement.*

Comment: @gdlmx Right, that's my point. The global statement is called a modifier. However, you can tell it to modify an object that does not yet exist. As soon as it does, THEN it will be modified. How does that work? That interaction between when I tell the interpreter `dog` will be global and when I actually define it.

Comment: The `global` statement is most emphatically *not* a "modifier". It is a parser instruction, and "does" nothing whatsoever to the variable.

Answer (score 2):

> What does the global statement **actually** do to the variable?

Absolutely nothing.

`global foo` means that any occurrences of the variable name `foo` in the scope of the function refer to a module-global `foo` variable instead of a function-call-local variable. It does nothing to the variable itself.

As for where such variables live, they don't really "live" anywhere. When such a variable is assigned, an entry will be created for them in the module's global variable dict. If the variable is `del`eted, the global variable dict entry will be erased. This is identical to what would happen if you were assigning and `del`eting these variables at module level without a `global` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

> The global is a directive to the parser.

as written in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-global_stmt). This means it doesn't change anything. Also notice that "it applies only to code parsed at the same time as the global statement". This can be tested in the below example

```
a=3
def foo():
  exec('global a')
  a=4

foo()
print(a) # 3
```

If `global` is a modifier as you said, then the last line will print 4. But that's not the case.